# Android app: Differentiate "folder deleted" from "permission removed" for this folder

Tags: android, permissions, documentfile

In my Android app, the user can select a folder thanks to Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
I can then write files to this folder.

The problem is that the user can delete this folder or remove the permission to access it.

In both cases, I would like to display a message to explain the user what is happening and how to fix this issue.

I need 2 different messages and so I need to differentiate these 2 cases

I wanted to use `DocumentFile.exists()` but it returns false in both cases.

How can I do that?

Comment: How can a user remove an access permission?

Comment: @blackapps, In Settings->Apps->your app->Storage, you can see the number of items you granted. There is also a 'clear access" button to remove these items.

Comment: An on new Android version, you you don't use an app for some time, Android may automatically remove all accesses.

Comment: Sorry, but i have never seen that a user can revoke there permanent directory permissions obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.  You are pretty mistaken and confusing.

Comment: Android can automatically remove a storage, camera, location,... permission yes. But will never remove one obtained by SAF like with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. You are pretty confusing.

Comment: @blackapps, you are right about permissions obtained by SAF. Sorry to be confusing, but Android doesn't make new features easy to learn. However, the problem stays the same as the user can manually removed these permissions.

Comment: ??? No. The user can not. Strange.. first you agree and then you deny. Confusing, confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251470/discussion-between-laurent-d-and-blackapps).